# Changing opacity css property using $.parent()

Tags: jquery, select, element, parent, opacity

I want to change the css property of an element like so:

Standard opacity of `a.archive_blocks_fa` is `0.5`. When `a.archive_blocks_sa` is hovered, `a.archive_blocks_fa` must have opacity `1.0`. When the hover event is ended, `a.archive_blocks_fa` must return back to opacity `0.5`.

HTML:

```
<div class="archive_blocks">
 <a href="#" class="archive_blocks_fa">
   <img width="142" height="142" src="#">
 </a>
 <div class="archive_blocks_name">
   <a href="#" class="archive_blocks_sa">Text</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've written this jQuery code:

```
$('a.archive_blocks_sa').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','1');
}, function(){
    $(this).parent('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

Guys, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `parent` of `archive_blocks_sa` is `archive_blocks_name`.

Comment: You have not read the [`.parent()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) properly.

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().prev('.archive_blocks_fa')...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`archive_blocks_fa` is the sibling of the parent of `archive_blocks_sa`(hovered element).

So you have to go to its `parent` level and then use `prev()` method to get the previous sibling(`archive_blocks_fa`) and set its opacity. Try this.

```
$('a.archive_blocks_sa').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','1');
}, function(){
    $(this).parent().prev('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

`.prev()` gets the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not traversing up the DOM correctly, try this instead:

```
$('a.archive_blocks_sa').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest(".archive_blocks").find('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','1');
}, function(){
    $(this).closest(".archive_blocks").find('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is that the element with class `archive_blocks_sa` *doesn't have a parent* with class `.archive_blocks_fa`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think `parent()` would only select the `archive_blocks_name` div, as it's a parent and `archive_blocks_fa` is not.
Try:

`$(this).parent().siblings('.archive_blocks_fa').css('opacity', '1');`

Comment: i missed the dot in the class selector :/